# Entity Framework дублирует записи

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть такие модели:

```
[Table("Accounts")]
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TaskBase> Tasks { get; set; }  
}


[Table("Tasks")]
public class Task
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Состоящих в отношении:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TaskBase>().HasRequired(p => p.Account).WithMany(a => a.Tasks).HasForeignKey(f => f.AccountId);
```

Свойство `Account` заполняется из вьюхи из списка уже существующих в БД. После сохранения `Task` в базу в таблице `Account` - вижу две одинаковые записи с разными `Id`. Как избежать подобного удвоения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего объекты `Task` и `Account` принадлежат разным экземплярам `DbContext`. Либо заполняйте только поле `AccountId`, либо перед сохранением проверяйте принадлежность обоих объектов одному экземпляру `DbContext`.

Comment: Я только начал изучать Entity и мне пока всё это не понятно. Могли бы вы рассказать подробнее?

Comment: А вроде понял, заработало нормально. Спасибо